Install older version of apps
I just want to install older version of some apps.
I'm more familiar with older version of some apps, in windows you could install older exe file in Ubuntu idk.

Debian-based systems are designed to work with a specific single version that is built to match the release (exception: Snap packages are designed to have multiple versions available). This is done specifically to reduce the support burden provided by volunteers. Folks can leave the marked path and wander into the wilderness -- it's your choice. We suggest that folks who leave the marked path should have the skills to maintain their custom setup, since our support advice will usually be to return to the marked path.

If you want a specific version; in many cases you can compile from source that version and have it thus match your system. Most of us opt to use the pre-prepared version which was made for our release though (thus our release dictates the version(s) available to us)

To check and install an older version of an app you should just run :
To check available version
apt-cache madison <package_name>

And then to install the version you want :
sudo apt-get install <package_name>=<version_number>

